# QML map - TLS initialization failed ERROR

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtlocation

I am currently creating an application that will be able to display maps. Before I add more advanced features, I would like to simply display a map of a certain area in the application. For this I used a bit of modified code from the Qt example "Minimal map". Code in map.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Rectangle {
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
        // specify plugin parameters if necessary
        // PluginParameter {
        //     name:
        //     value:
        // }
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14
    }
}
```

I display the map using QQuickWidget with the source set to my QML file. Unfortunately, the map is not displayed. Only a gray background and the inscription appear in the QuickWidget (I attach a picture to the post). In the QML Debugger Console i got the messages:

> "QObject:​:​connect(​QQuickWindow,​ QDeclarativeGeoMap)​:​ invalid nullptr parameter"

> "QGeoTileProviderOsm:​ Tileserver disabled at  QUrl(​"​http:​/​/​maps-​redirect.​qt.​io/​osm/​5.​8/​satellite"​)​"

> "QGeoTileFetcherOsm:​ all providers resolved"

> "QSslSocket:​:​connectToHostEncrypted:​ TLS initialization failed"

> "QGeoTileRequestManager:​ Failed to fetch tile (​8682,​4766,​14)​ 5 times,​ giving up.​ Last error message was:​ '​TLS initialization failed'​"

[image: Link to screenshot showing the problem]

Comment: You probably miss OpenSSL library.

Comment: It could also be the plugin is using an outdated tile server. Try maybe one of the other map types

Comment: @folibis Thank you! After installing this library, everything works.

Comment: I had this problem, too. I think there is no need to install OpenSSL. I found a solution here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/118089/error-when-running-minimal-map-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS is **windows** you should install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
and also you are using the osm plugin so you should be connected to the internet when Running the application.

your code in my system Runs like this :

[image: your code in my system Runs like this :]